# Convert EPS to JPEG with Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I have a script that currently takes a JPEG input, saves it to DB, copies it to folder, and then redirects. However, I have been told that we need to be able to take EPS files and convert them to JPEG now before anything else happens.

This is the added part of my script, that doesn't seem to work:

```
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filedims = getimagesize($filename);
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->newImage($filedims[0], $filedims[1], "white");
$imagick->compositeimage($filename, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
$imagick->setImageFormat("jpg");
$imagick->writeImage($filename);
```

From the [Imagick Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php), I see that the first parameter for `compositeimage()` should be an *"Imagick object which holds the composite image"*, but I'm not sure if my `$filename` at this point is?

I'm completely at a loss when it comes to object orientated PHP, and the `->` selector, but hopefully someone here can help me figure out what's going wrong.

**ERRORS ENCOUNTERED**

`Warning: getimagesize(fast-track_logo_text.eps): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /example.com/upload-company-logo.php on line 36`

How do you get the dimensions of an EPS file if `getimagesize()` doesn't work?! It's needed so I know the size of the canvas to create with `newImage()`.

`Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Imagick::compositeimage() must be an instance of Imagick, string given in /example.com/upload-company-logo.php on line 49`

Which looks to be what I thought the issue would be, using my `$filename` variable. If I adjust my code as follows, though:

```
$imagick = new Imagick($filename);
...
$imagick->compositeImage($imagick, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
...
```

I get a new, scarier-looking error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image 'fast-track_logo_text.eps': No such file or directory @ blob.c/OpenBlob/2480' in /example.com/upload-company-logo.php:47 Stack trace: #0 /example.com/upload-company-logo.php(47): Imagick->__construct('fast-track_logo...') #1 {main} thrown in /example.com/upload-company-logo.php on line 47`

Comment: The Apache error logs may give you some insight into any errors that may be occurring

Comment: Have found and added my errors to the initial question.

Comment: If my answer has solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise let me know if you're still having trouble

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file, PHP stores the file in the `/tmp/` directory under a randomly generated filename to avoid collisions with other files. So you must access the file using the temporary path to be able to access/move/manipulate it.

To do this, change `$_FILES['file']['name']` to `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

Don't forget to move the file somewhere more permanent at some point in your script as well! Once the script finishes executing, any created files in the `/tmp/` folder will be deleted.

For more information, you should check out PHP's documentation about [handling file uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't solved things. I will let you know my reworked code tomorrow when I'm back in the office, and let you know where I'm at now.

Comment: @mpdc Okay keep me posted. When you're back in the office try doing a `var_dump($_FILES)` so I know what you're sending to Imagick